# Android spinner and editText

Tags: android, android-edittext, spinner

my idea is to have a text field where I can input a name manually.

Additionally I do have a list of names. If there is at east 1 name in that list an icon should appear on the right of the `EditText` in order to open a `Spinner` to give a selection.

If no item is selected the `EditText` stays the same and if an item has been selected the `EditText` will have that item.

I'mworking with visibilities so far - but my problem is that the `onNothingSelected` seems not to get fired at all.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity  {

private Spinner spinner;
private EditText text2;
private ImageButton button2;
private String spinner_value = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    String[] str = {"","good", "dislike", "like", "hate", "moderate"};
    spinner.setPrompt("Set Text");
    ArrayAdapter<String> list = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, str);
    spinner.setAdapter(list);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                   int arg2, long arg3) {
            TextView tv = (TextView)arg1;
            spinner_value = tv.getText().toString();
            if(spinner_value.length() == 0)
            {
                spinner_value = "Nothing";
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), spinner_value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            text2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            button2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
            text2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            String myStr = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            text2.setText(myStr);
            text2.requestFocus();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NothingSelected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            text2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            button2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
            text2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            text2.requestFocus();
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the item at index 0 is selected when you spinner is created. So, even though the user doesn't actually do anything, the first item is selected. You can see this happen by setting a breakpoint (or some other notification) in onItemSelected() and seeing it get triggered on startup without the user doing anything.

For the onNothingSelected() callback to get triggered, whatever item is selected has to disappear.

Comment: In which case will it then be triggered?  If I open the Spinner and does not select anything by clicking somewhere else i isn't it then the case?

Comment: No. When you open the Spinner, the first item is already selected. For onNothingSelected() to be triggered,  the currently selected item has to become unavailable. For example, the view gets set to Gone.